# Get weekday and date of the following days in Android

Tags: android, string, date, calendar, simpledateformat

I got these 2 little functions to get the weekday and the date of today:

```
public String giveDate() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    return sdf.format(cal.getTime()).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + sdf.format(cal.getTime()).substring(1);
}

public String giveDay() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    Date d = new Date();
    String dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(d);
    return dayOfTheWeek.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + dayOfTheWeek.substring(1);
}
```

Is there any addition to my current functions to get the result of the following days?

Example of what I mean:

`giveDate(0)` and `giveDay(0)` will result in today.
`giveDate(1)` and `giveDay(1)` will result in tomorrow etc..

Thanks in advance

Comment: What should be the output? Did you searched over SO for the solution?

Comment: Hello, yes i already looked around for a possible solution without success. The output is explained in my question. If i call my 2 functions (giveDay() + " - " + giveDate()) i get Tuesday - Nov 26, 2013... what i need is an addition to get the following days. (giveDay(1) + " - " + giveDate(1)) (or something similar) have to result in Wednesday - Nov 27, 2013

Comment: Check if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20139385/name-of-day-in-string-format-with-days-to-furure/20139582#20139582
For any given day/date, you will have to set your Calendar instance accordingly and retrieve the value as per the new value set.

Comment: i guess it can help a bit. let me try to add something to my code... i'll get back to you in 10 mins. thanks meanwhile!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code

```
public String getDay(int dayFromToday) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar(); 
    today.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayFromToday); 
    return sdf.format(today.getTime()); 
}
```

Where calling way like

```
System.out.println(getDay(0));
System.out.println(getDay(1));
System.out.println(getDay(2));
System.out.println(getDay(3));
```

And output is

```
Nov 26, 2013
Nov 27, 2013
Nov 28, 2013
Nov 29, 2013
```

You can get previous day by using this method also. To get previous day pass negative value to this method.

For example

```
System.out.println(getDay(-3)); // 3 days before today
```

Output will be

```
Nov 23, 2013
```